# Repeat the string list in Scheme language

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to make a code with Scheme language.I want to input a list and return the string representation of the list where the first element is repeated one time, the second element repeats two times and third element repeats three times like

input is => (c d g)
output is => (c d d g g g)

I wrote a code with duplicating all elements. I should use loop for making repeat all elements from first one to last one with 1 to n times.(n is size of list). But I do not know how.

```
(define repeat
  (lambda (d)
    (cond [(null? d) '()]
          [(not (pair? (car d)))
           (cons (car d)
                 (cons (car d)
                       (repeat (cdr d))))]
          [else (cons (repeat (car d))
                      (repeat (cdr d)))])))

                (repeat '(a b c d e)) => aa bb cc dd ee


(define size
    (lambda (n)
        (if (null? n)               
             0                
            (+ 1 (size (cdr n)))))) 
(size '(A B C D)) => 4
```

Comment: You mean the output should be `"(c d d g g g)"` since that is a string representation of the list `(c d d g g g)`?  http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: What have you tried on the "actual" problem of repeating the Nth element N times? Instead of repeating every element 2 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make a few different functions for this.

- `repeat` (as you described) acts like this `(repeat '(c d g)) ;=> (c d d g g g)`

The best way to implement that is using a helper `(repeat-aux n lst)` which repeats the first element `n` times, the second element `n+1` times and so on.

Given that you can define:

```
(define (repeat lst) (repeat-aux 1 lst))
```

---

To implement `repeat-aux` you can use a recursion pattern like this

```
(define (repeat-aux n lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      ... (repeat-aux (+ n 1) (cdr lst) ...))
```

I'm just giving a sketch or outline of the function, not the whole thing. So that you can work on it yourself.

---

To implement repeat-aux I would also recommend making a helping function `(replicate n elt tail)` which works like this:

```
(replicate 3 'o '(u v w)) ;=> (o o o u v w)
```

---

I hope the idea of breaking it down into simple helper function makes it easier. Have a go and feel free to ask if you get stuck.